# Large-sample distribution of the Autocovariance function

Tags: time-series, distributions

I'm trying to understand property 1.1 below ($x_t$ is white noise), from Theorem A.7(also below).

From the formula for the $W$ matrix, using the more convenient one, I get $W_{pq}=0$ when $p\neq q$ and for $p=q$, $W_{pq}=\rho_x(0)^2=\sigma_x^4$. However, in property 1.1, I get $W_{pq}=1$.

So, where have I gone wrong?

Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I'm dyslexic a bit. Where I wrote autocovariance I should have written autocorrelation...

This is the problem...
In property 1.1 we're dealing with the asymptotic distribution of the autoCORRELATION, not autocovariance. And the correlation of white noise is 1 for $p=q$ and 0 otherwise, which explains the asymptotic covariance of the autocorrelation estimator.

Answer (score 0):

In theorem A.7, $\sigma_{\hat{p_x}(h)}^2 = \frac{W}{n}$ 
then for $n$ large, $\sigma_{\hat{p_x}(h)}^2 = \frac{W}{n} \approx \frac{1}{n}$

based on central limit theorem result $\sqrt{n} \; \hat{p_x} \xrightarrow{d} N(0,1)  $, [here's](https://www.google.co.id/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&ved=0CEIQFjAF&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.researchgate.net%2Fpublictopics.PublicPostFileLoader.html%3Fid%3D5462e90bd11b8b625a8b4617%26key%3Dda8f8579-8b58-4994-8bd1-c71ce6e2c3f1&ei=AkwOVeKrI5aOuATqloLwBw&usg=AFQjCNH6oT0QnfN3BNo5XJISzGYObOiB5Q&sig2=RIv149fkGZoR6TXISxJv3A&bvm=bv.88528373,d.c2E&cad=rja) for details.

Comment: Kurnia, the pdf just states what I would like to prove...